# Trouble with secure-file-priv for MySQL on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mysql, macos-mojave

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and haven't been able to find an answer that works for similar questions on this topic.

I am using MySQLWorkbench 8.0 on a MacOS Mojave. At the highest level, I am trying to import a couple of CSV files into MySQLWorkbench using the LOAD DATA INFILE command.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/users/Me/Desktop/Folder/File.csv'
INTO TABLE TESTTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv 
option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I perform a SHOW VARIABLES command on secure-file-priv and the result is NULL.

I believe that I need to create a my.ini or my.cnf file but I am unable to find an example here that works for me.

How can I create the my.ini or my.cnf file to edit the secure-file-priv to be able to change the NULL setting and set a directory to load files with LOAD DATA INFILE command?

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this https://superuser.com/a/1107175/290071